# Is it possible to work with something like WPF with C# in OS X?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, silverlight, macos

Can you work with some C# framework like Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) in OS X without installing a virtual machine with Windows? For example, using Wine can run .exe and also creates a virtual registry. I can create other partitions on my hard disk using BootCamp and install Windows. I can create a virtual Windows using Parallels Desktop or VMware Fusion, but it's not native working like another application in OS X running just one OS.

We can work in C# using MonoDevelop (now XamarinStudio) but can not work with WPF.

Then, you can install Microsoft Visual Studio on Mac and work with WPF and/or Silverlight?

Comment: You can still code in Silverlight/Moonlight http://www.mono-project.com/WPF

Comment: It is not so bad question, also i wonder if maybe with Wine applications would runs WPF applications.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, but the answer to my question is MonoMac. It is like a WPF in Mac. [link](www.mono-project.com/MonoMac)

Comment: In the medieval ages, the web was very hostile as evidenced by...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't work with WPF on Mac.

Mono currently doesn't support WPF because it's really hard to implement (WPF rendering is tied to the graphic card in some ways).

Maybe you want to try [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) (implementation of Silverlight for UNIX-based systems).

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight applications run on MAC OS in Safari or Firefox browsers [Silverlight plug-in for MAC OS](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26623/silverlight). Mono also has a version of Silverlight named Moonlight for Linux plarforms. No WPF on MAC OS. There is no development environment on MAC OS for Silverlight to my knowledge, just Silverlight apps running in browser.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't work with WPF outside the Windows platform. 
Before trying to work with WPF, I recommend this [MSDN series of articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) on what WPF means and other detailed specifications. Before working with something you must know what that thing is. Good luck!